# Finding the closure of the set $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n,$ where $A_n=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: y=x^2/n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, solution-verification

> For each $n\in\Bbb N,$ we define $$A_n=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: y=\frac{x^2}n\right\}.$$
> Let $A=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n.$ Find $\overline A$.

My attempt:

Each $A_n$ is closed as a graph of the continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R, f(x)=\frac{x^2}n$ and, therefore, all the limit points of $A_n$ are in $A_n,$ that is, in $A$.

I want to show that $\overline{A}=B:= A\cup \{(x,0):x\in\Bbb R\},$ by arguing $\{(x,0):x\in\Bbb R\}$ is  a subset of the set $A'$ of all the limit points of $A$ and $B$ is closed.

Let's take a fixed $x_0\in\Bbb R$ and define $y_n=\frac{x_0^2}n.$ Then $y_n\to 0$ and hence $(x_0,y_n)\to (x_0,0).$ We constructed a sequence converging to an arbitrary $(x_0,0)$ and it follows that the whole $x$ axis contains limit points of the set $A$.

Now, I want to show $B=A\cup\{(x,0):x\in\Bbb R\}$ is closed. For that purpose, let's observe $\Bbb R^2\setminus B$.

Let's define $C_n:=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:\frac{x^2}{n+1}<y<\frac{x^2}n\right\}.$ We can write $$C_n=\underbrace{\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y>\frac{x^2}{n+1}\right\}}_{D_1}\cap\underbrace{\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y<\frac{x^2}n\right\}}_{D_2}$$
Both $D_1$ and $D_2$ are open (for each point $(x',y')\in D_1$ or $(x',y')\in D_2$ we can find the shortest distance $d$ from a bounding parabola and take $r<d$ so that $B((x',y'),r)\subseteq D_1$ or $B((x',y'), r)\subseteq D_2$) and therefore, $C_n$ is open $\forall n\in\Bbb N$.

Also, there is a set $E=\{(x,y):\in\Bbb R^2:y>x^2\}$ and the lower half plane $F=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: y<0\}$ both of which are open.

Finally, we see $\Bbb R^2\setminus B=E\cup F\cup\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N} C_n.$
$\Bbb R^2\setminus B$ is open as a countable union of open sets, which implies $B$ is closed.

Is there anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: Just for clarity, use $y_n$ rather than $x_n.$ Then name $x_n$ gives the impression you are talking about $x$ values in the ordered pair. Not wrong, per se, but can lead to confusion.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you for the remark! I'll correct that into $y_n$.

Comment: There is a faster way to show that $D_i$ are open. Let $g_n(x,y)=y-f_n(x).$ Then $D_1=g_{n+1}^{-1}((0,\infty))$ and $D_2=g_n^{-1}((-\infty,0)).$ But that depends on a result about continued functions which you might or might not have reached. This is a more “topological” argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof that the $D_i$ are open is a little hand-wavy. Otherwise it is fine.

It is easier to prove that $B$ is closed.

Let $$C_n= \{(x,y)\mid 0\leq y\leq f_n(x)\}$$ and
$$B_n=A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_n\cup C_n$$

Show $C_n$ is closed, and includes all $A_i, i\geq n.$ Then $B_n$ is also closed and we can show easily that: $$B=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$$
Hence $B$ is closed.

---

Here’s an approach essentially the same as your approach, but using a uniform language to make it clearer.

> **Lemma:** If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function, then
> $$D_{f}^+=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid y>f(x)\}\\ D_{f}^-=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid y<f(x)\}$$ are both open in $\mathbb R^2.$ 
> **Proof:** The function $g(x,y)=y-f(x)$ is continuous, and $$D_f^{+}=g^{-1}((0,\infty))\\ D_f^{-}=g^{-1}((-\infty,0)).$$

Define $z(x)=0.$ Then:

$$\mathbb R^2\setminus B=D_{f_1}^+\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(D_{f_n}^{-1}\cap D_{f_{n+1}}^+\right)\cup D_z^-\tag1$$

So $\mathbb R^2\setminus B$ is open, and $B$ is closed.

$(1)$ is true because the $f_n$ are decreasing and converging to zero. So for any $(x,y)\notin B,$ either $y>f_1(x),$ or $f_n(x)>y>f_{n+1}(x)$ for some $n,$ or $y<0.$

$(1)$ is just a restatement of your approach, but I’m just using the one result about $D_f^{\pm}.$

This works for any decreasing sequence of functions such that $f_n(x)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

More generally, for a topological space $X$ and a decreasing sequence $f_n:X\to \mathbb R,$ of functions which converges to a continuous function $f$, the closure of the union of the graphs in $X\times\mathbb R$ is gotten by just adding the graph of $f.$

---

It’s true if $f_n$ is not decreasing, if it converges uniformly to $f.$

Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that for all $n>N,x\in X,$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon.$ So:

$$C_{\epsilon}=\bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i \cup \{(x,y)\mid f(x)-\epsilon\leq y\leq f(x)+\epsilon\}$$
is closed, and contains all $A_i.$ But $$\bigcap_{\epsilon>0} C_{\epsilon}$$ is then also closed, and it just the union of the $A_i$ and the graph for $f.$

---

A more univseral result:

> **Theorem:** f $f_n\to f$ and there is a sequence of decreasing decreasing continuous functions $g_m\to 0$ such that for every $m$ there is an $N_m$ so that for all $x$ and $n>N_m,$ $$f(x)-g_m(x)\leq f_n(x)\leq f(x)+g_m(x)$$ then the closure of $\bigcup A_i$ is just adding the graph of $f.$

This is more universal because it covers the uniform case (with $g_{m}(x)=\frac1m,$) and the monotone decreasing or increasing case (with $g_m(x)=|f_m(x)-f(x)|.$)

Then $$B_m=\bigcup_{i=1}^{N_m} A_i \cup \{(x,y)\mid | y-f(x)|\leq g_m(x)\}$$ is a sequence of closed sets and so:

$$B=\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty B_m$$ is closed.

---

For any $f_n\to f,$ we can define:

$$g_{m}(x)=\sup_{n\geq m} |f_n(x)-f(x)|.\tag1$$

This is defined for any $x,$ since $\{f_n(x)\}$ is convergent, and hence bounded. The $g_m$ are also nonnegative and decreasing, converging to $0.$

In most cases, it seems like $g_m$ will be continuous, in which case the result will hold.

But there are cases where it isn’t. They are strange cases. Like if $f_n(x)$ is a triangle with base $[0,1/n]$ and with height $1.$ Pointwise, this sequence converges to $0,$ but no $g_n$ will be continuous at $0.$

And, indeed, the closure of these graphs will be $$\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}\cup \{(0,y)\mid y\in[0,1]\}$$

I wonder if the $g_m$ defined in $(1)$ being continuous is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: First, sincerely thank you for your detailed answer and patience.I have a few questions, though.

$(1)$ due to the uniform convergence of nondecreasing $f_n$ to $f$, we have $\bigcup\limits_{i>N} A_i\subseteq\{(x,y)\mid f(x)-\varepsilon\le y\le f(x)+\varepsilon\}$ 

and that is the reason why, for each $\varepsilon>0 ,\quad\bigcup\limits_{i\in\Bbb N} A_i\subseteq C_\varepsilon\implies\bigcup\limits_{i\in\Bbb N} A_i\subseteq\bigcap\limits_{\varepsilon>0}C_\varepsilon.$

Comment: $(2)$ In the generalizations of the result, do we need $f_n$'s to be continuous? I thought so from the later statement $C_\varepsilon$ is closed.


$(3)$ In the end of your answer, how does $f_n$ map $x$ to a triangle? I'm confused a bit since the closure of the graphs is in $\Bbb R^2$